# Displaying date from calendar in label tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to collect the date from a calendar widget in tkinter using a button and then display that date in a label, so I defined a function to do so, however, it does not work and I get the error message "getdate() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and 'cont'"\

I am not sure why this is as I have included self and cont in the function brackets.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkcalendar import *



def getdate(self, cont):
    date_label.config(text="Today's date is " + cal.get_date()) #function to get date from 
 #calendar and display in label

#window = Tk()

#window.title("StudyFriendO")

LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 24)

class StudyFriendO(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title("StudyFriendO") #naming window title
        self.geometry('850x830') #size of window
        


        
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, HomePage, ToDoPage, TimetablePage): #list of multiple frames of program

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()






class StartPage(tk.Frame): #creating start page

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        


       
            

        label = tk.Label(self, text="StudyFriendO", font = LARGE_FONT, bg="#f2fcff")
        label.pack(fill="x")

        #place(x=315,y=100)

        photo1 = tk.PhotoImage(file NAME') #photo1 is a variable
        #label (window, image=photo1, bg="black") .grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E)
        panel = tk.Label(self, image = photo1)
        panel.image = photo1
        panel.pack(fill="x")

        #place(x=270,y=150)

        label2 = tk.Label(self, text="Enter today's date and your first name below:", bg="#f2fcff")
        label2.pack(fill="x", ipady=20)

        #place(x=305, y=400)

        
        cal = Calendar(self, background="#e0f6fc", disabledbackground="white", bordercolor="light blue", headersbackground="light blue", normalbackground="#e0f6fc", foreground="black", normalforeground='black', headersforeground='white', selectmode="day", year=2021, month=8, day=9)
        cal.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
        #(x=300,y=430) #calendar

        nameentry = tk.Entry(self, width=20, bg="white") #text input for users name
        nameentry.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.68, anchor='center')
        #(x=365, y=635)
        
        caldate = ttk.Button(self, text="Submit", 
                            command=getdate) #button to get current date
        caldate.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.63, anchor='center')

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Enter", 
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(HomePage)) #button to navigate page
        button1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.73, anchor='center')
        #(x=387,y=660)


        date_label = tk.Label(self, text="") #label to display date
        date_label.pack(pady=20)

        self.configure(bg='#f2fcff')
        

class HomePage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Home", font = LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="To Do",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(ToDoPage)) #button to navigate page
        button1.pack()

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Timetable",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(TimetablePage)) #button to navigate page
        button1.pack()

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(HomePage)) #button to navigate page
        button1.pack()



class ToDoPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="To Do", font = LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(HomePage)) #button to navigate page
        button1.pack()

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Timetable",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(TimetablePage)) #button to navigate page
        button1.pack()

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="To Do",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(ToDoPage)) #button to navigate page
        button1.pack()


class TimetablePage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Timetable", font = LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(HomePage)) #button to navigate page
        button1.pack()

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Timetable",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(TimetablePage)) #button to navigate page
        button1.pack()

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="To Do",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(ToDoPage)) #button to navigate page
        button1.pack()

app = StudyFriendO()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of issues with the given questions.

1. There is no reference for `date_label` & `cal` inside the `get_date()` function. `cal` may be an import error.
2. Moved `get_date()` inside the `StudyFriendO` class & renamed it to `set_date()`.
3. modified the way to handled this as a command from the submit button.

Have a look at the modified code & the output image.

```
import calendar
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkcalendar import *
from datetime import datetime


 #calendar and display in label

#window = Tk()

#window.title("StudyFriendO")

LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 24)

class StudyFriendO(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title("StudyFriendO") #naming window title
        self.geometry('850x830') #size of window




        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, HomePage, ToDoPage, TimetablePage): #list of multiple frames of program

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

    def set_date(self, cont):
        frame: StartPage = self.frames[cont]
        frame.date_label.config(text="Today's date is " + datetime.today().strftime("%B %d, %Y")) #function to get date from




class StartPage(tk.Frame): #creating start page

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)







        label = tk.Label(self, text="StudyFriendO", font = LARGE_FONT, bg="#f2fcff")
        label.pack(fill="x")

        #place(x=315,y=100)

        photo1 = tk.PhotoImage(file="1.png") #photo1 is a variable
        #label (window, image=photo1, bg="black") .grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E)
        panel = tk.Label(self, image = photo1)
        panel.image = photo1
        panel.pack(fill="x")

        #place(x=270,y=150)

        label2 = tk.Label(self, text="Enter today's date and your first name below:", bg="#f2fcff")
        label2.pack(fill="x", ipady=20)

        #place(x=305, y=400)


        cal = Calendar(self, background="#e0f6fc", disabledbackground="white", bordercolor="light blue", headersbackground="light blue", normalbackground="#e0f6fc", foreground="black", normalforeground='black', headersforeground='white', selectmode="day", year=2021, month=8, day=9)
        cal.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
        #(x=300,y=430) #calendar

        nameentry = tk.Entry(self, width=20, bg="white") #text input for users name
        nameentry.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.68, anchor='center')
        #(x=365, y=635)

        caldate = ttk.Button(self, text="Submit",
                            command=lambda: controller.set_date(StartPage)) #button to get current date
        caldate.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.63, anchor='center')

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Enter",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(HomePage)) #button to navigate page
        button1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.73, anchor='center')
        #(x=387,y=660)

        self.date_label = tk.Label(self, text="") #label to display date
        self.date_label.pack(pady=20)

        self.configure(bg='#f2fcff')


class HomePage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Home", font = LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="To Do",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(ToDoPage)) #button to navigate page
        button1.pack()

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Timetable",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(TimetablePage)) #button to navigate page
        button1.pack()

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(HomePage)) #button to navigate page
        button1.pack()



class ToDoPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="To Do", font = LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(HomePage)) #button to navigate page
        button1.pack()

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Timetable",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(TimetablePage)) #button to navigate page
        button1.pack()

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="To Do",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(ToDoPage)) #button to navigate page
        button1.pack()


class TimetablePage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Timetable", font = LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(HomePage)) #button to navigate page
        button1.pack()

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Timetable",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(TimetablePage)) #button to navigate page
        button1.pack()

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="To Do",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(ToDoPage)) #button to navigate page
        button1.pack()

app = StudyFriendO()
app.mainloop()
```

Output Image: [image]

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Now would there be any way to collect the date information from the start page, but then display the label on the home page? I tried to do this by pasting the label on the home page instead, but then there was an error saying there was no was no date label in the start page frame.

Comment: You can actually maintain another label for the homepage list like you've kept date_label in the StartPage class. 

add the following line in the StudyFriendO.set_date() function once you add a date_label inside HomePage.__init__(). 


frame2: HomePage = self.frames[HomePage]
frame2.date_label.config(text="Today's date is " + datetime.today().strftime("%B %d, %Y")) #function to get date from